# Good practice to call System.gc()

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I read many articles about bad practice to call `System.gc()`.

I understand that no guaranty at all that `JVM` will react on this call.

And I know that `System.gc()` is *pretty good indicator of fundamentally broken code*.

But, if I have web backend server and I need to process many resources at server load stage. And after load memory is full of garbage.

And I know that my server will be used only in Ubuntu with `Hotspot` `JDK1.8` and this `JDK` reacts on `System.gc()`.

Is it bad to call `System.gc()` only once after load and before I open server for users?

Is there someone who does the same thing?

Comment: Can you share a link to this article?

Comment: @TheLostMind Your link doesn't say that about GC at all. It only says that about thread priorities. The statement doesn't even make sense. GC isn't performed by the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to call `System.gc()`. Do use a memory analysis tool to check that it's helping in your case.

The spec can't guarantee any results since the vm might've just done a GC.

Comment: The spec doesn't guarantee any results, but it doesn't state why.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to call it at all. It isn't guaranteed that it will do anything, and it is guaranteed that GC will be performed before an `OutOfMemoryException` can be thrown. And if it does do something it may waste CPU time.

Comment: @alfasin By performing GC at an inappropriate time.

Comment: but according to the OP's description it sounds like it *is* an appropriate time.

Comment: @alfasin Not to me. The time to peform GC is in the background, or when the system needs memory, and the application is not a competent judge of that. I haven't used `System.gc()` since about 1.1.3 in 1997, and it was probably unnecessary then.

Comment: Indeed, but since this call is not forcing GC, but merely used as a "recommendation", why would it cause any harm?

Comment: You can't assume that. It isn't specified. Even the call itself is a waste of cycles. I dealt a while ago with JXL which is full of GC calls, and it behaves atrociously unless you turn them off, which fortunately you can.

Comment: The docs use the word "suggests": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc()

Comment: I know what it says. Read the next sentence, which basically contradicts that. You can't assume what it does or doesn't do.